# Refer tags outside Iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

the structure is

```
<tr rel="param1">
<td>
    <iframe>
       <body>
         <input type="input"/>

        </body>

   </iframe>
</td></tr>
```

Now I want to get the referernce of the tr from the input tag which is inside the iFrame. I tried `$("input").closest('tr')`. But this is not working. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In a iframe represents a complete new page inside another. You cannot easily access the parents elements. But you can load JQuery in the iFrame too, to have the methods available there and you can use Javascript's like

```
parent.document.getElementById('....');
```

or

```
parent.$("input").closest('tr') // acces directly parents JQuery, not tested maybe working...
```

Answer (score 0):

Content in an IFrame can't be allowed to access content outside the IFrame. This protects the outer website from remote code execution style attacks.